# Is there a practical example on how to define the Region of Practical Equivalence (ROPE) in Bayesian estimation?

Tags: bayesian

I've been reading up on Bayesian estimation and see the Region of Practical Equivalence (ROPE) as a potentially very useful concept. It seems to be analogous to the rejection region in classical hypothesis testing.

Is there a practical example(s) (preferably in R) that walks you on how we select the ROPE for a particular user case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explained here.
http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/how-much-of-bayesian-posterior.html
Each particular case/example/domain of interest has its own ROPE. Selecting a ROPE does not depend on a particular analysis example but instead is based on the consequences of the data you are dealing with and what you consider the ROPE should be.